# What's the minimum amount of oil for making popcorn?

Tags: popcorn

My wife makes popcorn by adding the corn to a pan, then tilt the pan and add oil until the popcorn is just covered. This seems to be a lot of oil. Does anybody know how to make popcorn with less oil?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I do it is put 1-2 tbsp of oil in my pot, add 1/3 cup or so of corn, cover, and heat on medium until it starts popping, then turn down a bit and shake the pot occasionally until it is all popped. So, not oil free, but not a whole lot of oil either.

Comment: Sounds like way less oil to me :-)

Comment: Yup, this is how I do it too.  Super tasty and very little oil.

Comment: I add a tablespoon or two of (peanut) oil, throw in about three kernels, and once they've popped the oil is obviously hot enough,then pour in the full batch.

Comment: I tried it and it works, see [picture here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/can-you-make-popcorn-in-a-pressure-cooker)

Comment: That's still too much oil, you just need to coat the bottom of the pan, not drown it

Comment: @TFD, 1-2 tbsp does coat the bottom of my pan, which is large and shallow. Only one I've got.

Comment: 1-2 tsp should be enough, not tbsp, even for a large pan. Adding to much just makes greasy popcorn

Comment: Maybe it depends on how much popcorn you make. I usually do 1/3 or 1/2 cup. Never been greasy.

Answer (score 10):

If you use an [air popper](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Dgarden&field-keywords=air+popper), you don't need any oil.

I still add a little bit back in (with a pump sprayer), so the salt will stick ... but you could theoretically use none at all.n

Comment: +1 I prefer this method because you don't have to heat your oil at all...I usually drizzle on a very fruity olive oil, though a pump sprayer would make it easier. Making popcorn in a pan with a good olive oil would be a very bad idea, as the oil would go rancid from the heat.

Comment: Probably a good method if you're planning on making it often.

Answer (score 4):

The minimum amount of oil to do popcorn is ZERO! here is [the trick](http://www.squawkfox.com/2010/07/27/popcorn-recipe-gourmet-popcorn/) to make popcorn with less oil!

**Edit:** The method described by 'the trick' is to add a half cup of corn to a plain brown paper bag. Fold the bag closed, and put it in the microwave for 3 minutes on high. When the corn stops popping (less then two pops per second), take it out of the microwave. Add flavoring to taste.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you were to summarize the technique right here in your answer.  This way, we still have the information if the linked page goes away.

Comment: +1, The minimum amount of oil is, indeed, zero. You can also achieve that with an air-popper as described by Joe.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip @BaffledCook I will ensure to make it this way the next time. edit: dunno why I can't make your username resolve as expected. Might be a js issue with my linux chromium browser.

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading when I bought my whirley pop, to use 2 tablespoons of oil per 1/2 cup of corn. It works out fine for me, although if I'm cooking it with butter as the oil, I usually add 3 tablespoons (because butter isn't entirely fat).

Comment: I think butter is a little under 20% water, and the milk solids don't have much volume, so 3 tablespoons of butter is closer to 2.5 tablespoons of oil, so you're probably overcompensating a bit. You could probably get away with 2.5 tablespoons if you're trying to minimize oil like the OP.

Comment: Butter is, if I recall, 42% fat, and the rest is milk (excluding milk fat), and water. Don't quote me on this though.

Comment: Nope. Look up nutrition facts. http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/dairy-and-egg-products/0/2

Comment: You're right, wikipedia lists it as being 81% fat by weight.

Answer (score 1):

In my Whirley pop I use half a teaspoon for 1/3 of a cup of kernels, less oil the healthier it is, works for me, I eat popcorn everyday!